# NSInteger returning 0 if NSString is NULL

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsinteger

This could be the simplest one but I am not able to find the exact cause. Instead to explain in words following is my code:

```
NSString *str = @"";
NSInteger tempInteger = [str integerValue];

if (tempInteger == 0)
{
  NSLog (@"do something");
}
```

If `NSString` returning `NULL` then `NSInteger` returning 0 and if `NSString`has some value then `NSInteger` returning same value.

But when `NSString` is `NULL` then I want `NSInteger` should return `NULL` not 0 but I am not able to validation `NSInteger` as `NULL`.

How can I get `NULL` value in `NSInteger` if `NSString` is NULL?

Comment: `id number = str ? [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[str integerValue]] : [NSNull null];`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NULL` is a pointer; NSInteger is a C primitive that can only hold numbers. It is not possible for an NSInteger to ever be `NULL`. (Sidenote: when we speak of Objective-C object pointers, we use `nil` rather than `NULL`.)

Instead, if you wish to handle only cases where the integer value is 0, but the string *is not* `NULL`, you should change your condition as follows:

```
if (tempInteger == 0 && str != nil)
```

However, in your case, the string is not `nil`; it is merely an existent--but empty--string. If you wish to also check for that, your condition could become:

```
if (tempInteger == 0 && [str length] > 0)
```

This checks *both* cases because a `nil` string will return length `0`. (In fact, any method sent to `nil` will return `0`, `nil`, `0.0`, etc. depending on the return type.)

Comment: Note that if your string cannot be converted into an integer (for example @"hi") your `NSInteger` will also be 0.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you could implement a logic such as this:

1. Check if your string is indeed an integer
2. Try to convert it
3. If it's equal to 0 do something

Something like this would do the trick:

```
NSString *str = @"";
NSInteger tempInteger = [str integerValue];
NSCharacterSet *cs = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
BOOL safe = [cs isSupersetOfSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:str]] && str.length > 0;

if (safe && tempInteger == 0)
{
  NSLog (@"do something");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An integer can only hold numbers an nut null value. In this case you should first check the length of string to check if it's null

Answer (score 0):

`NSInteger` is a scalar variable type. The value `NULL` (actually `nil` in ObjectiveC), indicating a pointer towards the address `0`, when cast to an NSInteger will be `0`.

For accomplishing your task, you will have to compare `NSString` against `nil` before converting it towards an integer.

```
if (str == nil)
{
   //our string is invalid
}
else
{
    tempInteger = [str integerValue];
}
```